# flutter:: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..14: 15

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

I made a function to delete saved recording files.
The delete function works fine.
However, if it is deleted, an error

> 'RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..14: 15'

will occur and it will look like the picture above.
How can I solve this?

This is the delete function.

```
  _delete() {
    widget.file[widget.index].delete(recursive: true);
    setState(() {
      position = new Duration();
      widget.file.removeAt(widget.index);
    });
  }
```

This is my listview code.

```
class _AudioViewerState extends State<AudioViewer> {
  var audioPath;
  var directory;
  List file = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getFiles();
  }

  void getFiles() async {
    directory = (await getExternalStorageDirectory())!.path;
    setState(() {
      file = Directory("$directory").listSync();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    var width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        title: Text(
          "Audio List",
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: CustomPaint(
          child: ListView.builder(
            reverse: true,
            itemCount: file.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return AudioViewerCustomTile(
                text: file[index].path.split('/').last,
                path: file[index].path.toString(),
                height: height,
                width: width,
                file: file,
                index: index,
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the file with the delete function.

```
class DialogBuilder extends StatefulWidget {
  final String path;
  final int index;
  final List file;
  DialogBuilder({required this.path,required this.index,required this.file});

  @override
  _DialogBuilderState createState() => _DialogBuilderState();
}

class _DialogBuilderState extends State<DialogBuilder> {
  late AudioPlayer audioPlayer;
  bool _isplaying = false;
  var _icon = Icons.play_arrow;
  var _deleteicon = Icons.delete;
  Color _color = Colors.deepOrangeAccent;
  Duration position = Duration();
  Duration duration = Duration(seconds: 1);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 200,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  child: IconButton(
                    iconSize: 100,
                    onPressed: () {
                      if (!_isplaying) {
                        _play();
                      } else {
                        _stop();
                      }
                    },
                    icon: Icon(_icon),
                    color: _color,
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  child: IconButton(
                    iconSize: 50,
                    onPressed: () {
                      _delete();
                    },
                    icon: Icon(_deleteicon),
                  ),
                ),
              ]
            )
          ),

          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: LinearProgressIndicator(
              backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
              valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Colors.deepOrangeAccent),
              value: (position.inMilliseconds / duration.inMilliseconds) * 1.0,
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  _getDuration(position),
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                ),
                Text(
                  _getDuration(duration),
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                )
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  String _getDuration(Duration duration) {
    String twoDigits(int n) {
      if (n >= 10) return "$n";
      return "0$n";
    }

    String twoDigitMinutes = twoDigits(duration.inMinutes.remainder(60));
    String twoDigitSeconds = twoDigits(duration.inSeconds.remainder(60));
    return "${twoDigits(duration.inHours)}:$twoDigitMinutes:$twoDigitSeconds";
  }

  _play() {
    audioPlayer.resume();
    setState(() {
      _isplaying = true;
      _icon = Icons.pause;
      _color = Colors.blueGrey;
    });
  }

  _stop() {
    audioPlayer.release();
    setState(() {
      position = new Duration();
      _isplaying = false;
      _icon = Icons.play_arrow;
      _color = Colors.deepOrangeAccent;
    });
  }

  _delete() {
    widget.file[widget.index].delete(recursive: true);
    setState(() {
      position = new Duration();
      widget.file.removeAt(widget.index);
    });
  }

  _stateListener(PlayerState state) {
    print(" In _stateListener  the state of AudioPlayer :- " +
        state.toString() +
        "\n");
    if (state == PlayerState.COMPLETED) {
      Navigator.pop(context);
      _stop();
    }
  }
```

Comment: how many elements you have?

Comment: There were a total of 16 elements from 0 to 15, and after deleting one, 15 remained.

Comment: can you share more code?

Comment: I added listview code. Can you check my post again?

Comment: In which file you have declared delete function?

Comment: I have uploaded an additional file containing the delete function!

Comment: Can you try printing or debug how many items get deleted after single deletion

Comment: Your delete function is at a lower hierarchical level than the widget that loads the content, move the delete to the same level as the ListView.

Comment: In my code, I can't move the delete function into the listview. Is it possible to make the level the same even if the file location is different from the listview and delete function?

Comment: Looking at your code it is possible to move the delete to the same level as the listview, I also don't see a problem in the location of the file, the problem I see is the child applying setstate to update the parent, the setstate must be at the same level as the listview so index is updating correctly.

Comment: I moved the play, stop, delete functions to the same level as the listview! Your solution was very helpful. The delete function works fine, but suddenly the play and stop functions don't work. If you know anything about this issue, could you please answer it? This is my new code:: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70274420/flutter-unhandled-exception-platformexceptionunexpected-error-uristring-j

Answer (score -2):

The List file = []; is an empty list, so when you try to do itemCount = file.length, it displays an error, try giving the List file; a value instead of a an empty list and im sure it will work

Comment: Your answer doesn't make sense, the error clearly indicates that the index is out of range, I understand your desire to comment but only post an answer that can contribute to the question or wait for a score to comment.