# flutter:: Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(Unexpected error!, uriString, java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString

Tags: flutter, dart

```
    import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
    import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
    import 'dart:io';
    import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    
    class AudioViewer extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _AudioViewerState createState() => _AudioViewerState();
    }
    
    class _AudioViewerState extends State<AudioViewer> {
      List file = [];
      var audioPath;
      var directory;
      late AudioPlayer audioPlayer;
      bool _isplaying = false;
      var _icon = Icons.play_arrow;
      var _deleteicon = Icons.delete;
      Color _color = Colors.deepOrangeAccent;
      Duration position = Duration();
      Duration duration = Duration(seconds: 1);
    
      int indexindex = 0;
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        getFiles();
        _setupAudioPlayer();
      }
    
      void getFiles() async {
        directory = (await getExternalStorageDirectory())!.path;
        setState(() {
          file = Directory("$directory").listSync();
        });
        print(file.toString());
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        var height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
        var width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            elevation: 0,
            title: Text(
              "Audio List",
            ),
          ),
          body: Container(
              child: ListView.builder(
                reverse: true,
                itemCount: file.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Card(
                    elevation: 5,
                    child: ExpansionTile(
                        title: Text(
                          'Record ${index}',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                        onExpansionChanged: ((newState) {
                          if (newState) {
                            indexindex = index;
                            setState(() {
                            });
                          }
                        }),
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            height: 100,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10,0,10,0),
                            child: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                    child: Row(
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Container(
                                            child: IconButton(
                                              iconSize: 40,
                                              onPressed: () {
                                                if (!_isplaying) {
                                                  _play();
                                                } else {
                                                  _stop();
                                                }
                                              },
                                              icon: Icon(_icon),
                                              color: _color,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          Container(
                                            child: IconButton(
                                              iconSize: 30,
                                              onPressed: () {
                                                file[index].delete(recursive: true);
                                                setState(() {
                                                  file.removeAt(index);
                                                  position = new Duration();
                                                });
                                              },
                                              icon: Icon(_deleteicon),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ]
                                    )
                                ),
    
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                  child: LinearProgressIndicator(
                                    backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
                                    valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Colors.deepOrangeAccent),
                                    value: (position.inMilliseconds / duration.inMilliseconds) * 1.0,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                  child: Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Text(
                                        _getDuration(position),
                                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        _getDuration(duration),
                                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          )
                        ]
                    )
                );
                },
              ),
          ),
        );
      }
    
      String _getDuration(Duration duration) {
        String twoDigits(int n) {
          if (n >= 10) return "$n";
          return "0$n";
        }
    
        String twoDigitMinutes = twoDigits(duration.inMinutes.remainder(60));
        String twoDigitSeconds = twoDigits(duration.inSeconds.remainder(60));
        return "${twoDigits(duration.inHours)}:$twoDigitMinutes:$twoDigitSeconds";
      }
    
      _play() {
        audioPlayer.resume();
        setState(() {
          _isplaying = true;
          _icon = Icons.pause;
          _color = Colors.blueGrey;
        });
      }
    
      _stop() {
        audioPlayer.release();
        setState(() {
          position = new Duration();
          _isplaying = false;
          _icon = Icons.play_arrow;
          _color = Colors.deepOrangeAccent;
        });
      }
    
      _stateListener(PlayerState state) {
        print(" In _stateListener  the state of AudioPlayer :- " +
            state.toString() +
            "\n");
        if (state == PlayerState.COMPLETED) {
          //Navigator.pop(context);
          _stop();
        }
      }
    
      _setupAudioPlayer() async {
        position = new Duration(seconds: 0);
        audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
        await audioPlayer.setUrl(file[indexindex].path.toString());
        await audioPlayer.setReleaseMode(ReleaseMode.STOP);
    
        audioPlayer.onAudioPositionChanged.listen((Duration p) {
          print('Current position: $p');
          setState(() => position = p);
        });
    
        audioPlayer.onDurationChanged.listen((Duration d) {
          print('Max duration: $d');
          setState(() => duration = d);
        });
        audioPlayer.onPlayerStateChanged.listen(_stateListener);
      }
    
    
    
    }
```

I made a function to record voice and play/delete recorded files. I used the audioplayers package to create a function to play recording files.
The delete button works fine. But when I press the play button, the recorded file didn't play and the following error occurred.

> E/flutter (17278): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)]
> Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(Unexpected error!, uriString,
> java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString

How can I solve this?

Comment: You declared `audioPlayer` as `late`, but you instantiate it in an async function `_setupAudioPlayer`. Playing with fire, there's no guarantee that will be initialized by the time you use it. I'd rather make it nullable and check for null on every use... so you can skip trying to use it while it's not initialized.

Comment: I deleted late and did null check, but the same error still occurs.

Comment: Without seeing the full stacktrace, I am not sure where this is coming from but it is clearly a Java library error... my guess is that it's coming from the player package, try filling an issue with them: https://github.com/bluefireteam/audioplayers/issues